# How to inspect elements from NSArray and NSDictionary in xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.6

I installed the xcode 4.6. In the release notes I found below line:

> Debugger can inspect elements within `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` objects.

I can view the values using "po" command. Is it referring same?

OR

Is there any other technique made avail for developer to inspect the elements of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` without using "po" command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gdb window you can use po to inspect the object.

set breakpoint after the objects are added you can inspect what is in the dictionary

**Question what is GDB?**

gdb is in fact a prompt in the Console, where you can input commands. By typing "po object_name" you got the object content printed in the console. [For More Detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gdb)

```
 NSMutableDictionary* dictForData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dictForData setObject:@"test1" forKey:@"string1"];
    [dictForData setObject:@"test2" forKey:@"string2"];
```

**Output**

```
(gdb) po dictForData
{
  string1 = test1;
  string2 = test2;
}
```

### Another option for the Log Data.

setp 1 :[image]

step 2 : [image]

step 3 : [image]

step 4 : [image]

here is the methods which is use by me.

Comment: Thanks.. Its the same feature which is present in previous versions of xcode. I mean cant we see the elements on mouse hover? We can inspect properties of an object using mouse. Same is applicable for dict and array?

Answer (score 2):

If the array has data, put a breakpoint next to it. It will stop execution at that point.

Then just hover over it.

Example:[image]

Next: [image]

Hope this helps. Don't need to "po" or print description...

EDIT:

I just did this:

[image]

Comment: Hi lakesh. I have updated my Xcode to 4.6 but this feature is not working for me. do you have any idea?

Comment: i am using in Xcode 4.6. its working.. or should say always will work... did you put a break point?

Comment: Yes on the same line where I read Dictionary. it give me value in consol but happen nothing when I hover it. If you find something related to this comment here. thanks

Comment: just edited my answer.. i am able to do it... just hover over it...the variable should be pointed with red dots and have the value appear over it...